# Encoding issue on PHP Insert Statement and MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem inserting text into a mysql database with jquery and php. I have a jquery script that uses .ajax to pass parameters to a php page that does the insert. The result is text in my database that looks like this "Â CC". I want it to be "* CC". I know this probably has to do with UTF-8 encoding but I can't figure it how to fix it. My DB tables are "utf8_unicode_ci". Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

My .ajax code is...

```
var comment = "* CC";
$.ajax({
    url: "php/add_riw_report.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { comment: comment  },
});
```

And in firebug the POST source is...

```
&grade=*%C2%A0CC
```

I have this at the top of my php page...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

And the insert php code is...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
        riw_events  
    VALUES(
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["comment"])."'
    )";
$rs=$db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Dont use mysql , go for mysqli or pdo sql

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDO object must be configured to use utf8 charset

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=UTF8");
```

For Mysqli
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

```
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: I'm not using PDO...I'm using MySQLi. Should I do the same with that?

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, there's absolutely no reason to be using `mysql_real_escape_string`, that thing is dangerous. Use using prepared statements and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query.

Comment: switched to PDO and removed old mysql_real_escape_string. thanks, it is working! looking at prepared statements now